# SQL query from Two tables and a link table to return all of table c for each row of table a with nulls where the is no link in table b

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the schema:

```
Table a: worker_role_desription,role
Linking Table b: role,stepid, permission
Table c: stepid, step_description
```

I need to return a full list of `step_descriptions` from `c` for each role from `a` with the permission from `b` if it exists and `'none'` if it doesn't.

I have tried various ways of joining the tables but have failed to return what I need.

Comment: Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the expected output for that sample data; and **YOUR** attempt that does not work. Having the sample data and corresponding expected output would help us to understand what a "full list" means to you and how you would expect to get permissions that do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```sql
SELECT worker_role,
       step_description,
       COALESCE(permission, 'none') AS permission
FROM   a
       CROSS JOIN c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
       ON (a.role = b.role AND c.stepid = b.stepid)
ORDER BY
       a.role,
       c.stepid
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (worker_role, description, role PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT 'Role'|| LEVEL, 'Role Descr'||LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE c (stepid PRIMARY KEY, step_description) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'Step Descr'||LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE b(role, stepid, permission) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'RW' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 'W' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE b
  ADD CONSTRAINT b__role__fk FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES a(role)
  ADD CONSTRAINT b__stepid__fk FOREIGN KEY (stepid) REFERENCES c(stepid);
```

Outputs:

> | WORKER_ROLE | STEP_DESCRIPTION | PERMISSION |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Role1 | Step Descr1 | R |
> | Role1 | Step Descr2 | R |
> | Role1 | Step Descr3 | RW |
> | Role2 | Step Descr1 | R |
> | Role2 | Step Descr2 | none |
> | Role2 | Step Descr3 | W |
> | Role3 | Step Descr1 | none |
> | Role3 | Step Descr2 | none |
> | Role3 | Step Descr3 | none |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7290aefd951fc6479f7e833d9eced3cf)*

Comment: You're a star, I hadn't come across cross join before. Does just what I needed.